# Cinnamon settings will not open on 12.04 (Cinnamon 1.6.7 stable)

Tags: 12.04, cinnamon

Have Cinnamon 1.6.7 (stable) for Ubuntu 12.04 Precise installed. Cannot open the Cinnamon settings Panel. I have tried both Stable & Nightly same thing. Have changed 1 item in `/usr/share/cinnamon/js/ui/layout.js` from this [Page](http://misha.beshkin.lv/disable-hot-corner-hover-action-in-linux-mint-12/) (look in comment Section).

I Can change it back if needed. Want to able to `Disable Hot Corners` but cannot change since I can't get into Cinnamon settings panel.

Any help would be appreciated?

```
Dell Latitiude D600
2GB Ram
32 Mb of video ram
```

Also on this laptop is a Non-Pae kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I just got this same problem in Ubuntu 12.04 and was able to resolve it by installing python-pexpect and python-imaging packages:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pexpect python-imaging
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the following in terminal:

```
cinnamon-settings hotcorner
```